# C++ Custom Iterator

Tags: c++, class, for-loop, linked-list, iterator

I have two classes that implement a data structure similar to a linked list. We'll call them Node and List. To trim the fat of all the constructors and other methods, they essentially look like this:

```
    class Node {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
        using value_type = Node;
        using pointer = Node*;
        using reference = Node&;
        using size_type = size_t;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

        // Accessor functions
        bool operator!= (value_type const& n) const;
        bool operator== (value_type const& n) const;
        reference operator*();
        pointer operator&();
        pointer operator->();
        value_type const& operator++() const;
    };

    class List {
    private:
        typedef Node* iterator;
        typedef const Node* const_iterator;
    public:
        // Iterators
        iterator begin();
        const_iterator begin() const;
        iterator end();
        const_iterator end() const;

        // Operator overloads
        Node& operator*() const;
        const List* operator&() const;
        const List* operator->() const;
    };
```

I am trying to achieve something to the effect of:

```
for (Node n : List)
{
    // Some stuff
}
```

Yet I keep getting the (Visual Studio) error `this range-based 'for' statement requires a suitable "begin" function and none was found`

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include an actual [mcve]. The loop you show would not build because of other errors.

Comment: That should work (assuming `List` is a typo for a variable of type `List`).

Comment: Once the typo is fixed I [can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/qicCRm)

Comment: @john, turns out I'm just thick as fudge. After reviewing your comment and scratching my head at how it could be so, I realized that my actual List in implementation was generated with "new" and so (Node n : *List) did the trick. Thanks for the help!